# How can I make a new OpenCMS content type I can drop onto pages

Tags: content-management-system, opencms

I'm developing with OpenCMS, and so far, I've gotten a bit of an understanding with templates, model pages, how I can make spaces to drop in editable content, etc.

I have some elements I want to drop in that are not standard content types like Text Block or Flexible Content. In fact these elements don't exist at all.

I want to make something that:

1. Contains HTML that I write
2. Has only certain parts that my clients can edit easily.

I don't want my clients to have to get into HTML in a Flexible Content widget to for instance, edit some text inside a jQuery accordion or put a title on the handle of the jQuery accordion.

Help needed. OpenCMS terminology is seeming a little muddy to me, too. Please reference key words if you're an expert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am no expert in OpenCms, but as far as I know, you are able to define your own structured content type just like an v8.Article in an .xsd file.
There you can set fields that can be edited in ADE. Your HTML-Code can be added in a custom formatter-jsp.
Hope this helps a bit. The OpenCms documentation ist not very extensive...
Alkacon offers support, but at very high prices...

Comment: that's what I had concluded from mucking through the documentation. thanks @maximilian009 . Still need the specifics...